# how to change the height of a grid row in wpf using storyboard

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, row, storyboard

I have a `Grid` with 2 rows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="OtherContactsRow" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    Something here
</Grid>
```

and 2 `Storyboard`s:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MaximizedStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation From="20" To="150"  Duration="0:0:2"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="OtherContactsRow"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" >    
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="MinimizedStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation From="150" To="20" Duration="0:0:2"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="OtherContactsRow"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

When I try to modify the height of the row named `OtherContactsRow` I received the following error:

`'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Height' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.GridLength'.`

Any solutions?

Comment: The answer is here [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GridLengthAnimation.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GridLengthAnimation.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

You could try the `ActualHeight` property. It is a `double`.

Comment: Now I receive this error: 'ActualHeight' Storyboard.TargetProperty path does not point to a DependencyProperty.