# Changing grid column's/row's width/height by storyboard animation in Windows Store App

Tags: grid, storyboard, windows-store-apps, timeline

I'm looking for some method to change grid column's width (or row's height) by animtion defined in `Storyboard`. I have already found some solutions for WPF apps, but they are all useless in case of Windows Store programming, eg.:

[Grid Column changing Width when animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242072/grid-column-changing-width-when-animating?rq=1)

[how to change the height of a grid row in wpf using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017448/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-grid-row-in-wpf-using-storyboard?rq=1)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18379/WPF-Tutorial-Part-2-Writing-a-custom-animation-cla

Is such result obtainable by creating a custom class, inheriting from Timeline? If so, which components should be overrode for proper implementation?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a simple `DoubleAnimation`. Make sure to set `EnableDependentAnimation=True`, as outline [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj819807.aspx#dependent).

One thing to realize when trying things out is that `ColumnDefinitions` are a `GridLength` `struct`. You can find more information on them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx). You will need to have the animation set the `Value` property.

Comment: The GridLength.Value property doesn't have a setter. I believe it would also need to be a dependency property to work with a DoubleAnimation.

Comment: Ah, you're partially correct. `GridLength` is a `struct`, so you need to set the `ColumnDefinition`'s `Width` to a new `Gridlength`.

Comment: Could you post some example code of how to do this with a DoubleAnimation? It would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample method to animate a  Grid ColumnDefinition MaxWidth.

```
    private void Animate(ColumnDefinition column)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        CubicEase ease = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.EasingFunction = ease;
        animation.Duration = duration;
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        animation.From = 1000;
        animation.To = 0;
        animation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, column);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth)");

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```